# Is it semantically appropriate to have a header column in HTML?

Tags: html, html-table, semantic-markup

I have a table of information, but instead of the typical table where the headings are across the top:

```
Foo | Fnord | Fizzy | Buzz
----|-------|-------|-----------------
  42| Yes   | No    | Mr. mann
  13| Yes   | Flarg | Colonel Mustard
   1| Plum  | No    | Ms. Scarlet
```

I would like to put it down the side:

```
Foo   | 42       | 13              | 1
Fnord | Yes      | Yes             | Plum
Fizzy | No       | Flarg           | No
Buzz  | Mr. Mann | Colonel Mustard | Ms. Scarlet
```

Evidently it's allowed by doing something like

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Heading 1</th><td>Data 1</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Heading 2</th><td>Data 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

So I plan on doing it anyway, but I did want to check if this had any sort of break in semantics or anything else. Is this the correct way to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong about doing this.  To make it more accessible, add the scope="row" attribute on the TH tags which tells assistive technologies that the header is infact for the row (not the column).

See example 1 here: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63

Comment: +1.  Just to add to this, another W3 doc even has an example with headers in both rows and columns, so I think it's fine: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.1